# MySQL SELECT field value(s) contained in query string

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Supposing:

**phrase 1**: I am spiderman and I have a potato

**phrase 2**: I am a spider and I like potatoes

Table:

```
column_id | column_str
1         | spiderman
2         | potatoes
```

I want to perform an SQL query where the input is the **phrase**, and it should get as a result:

**For phrase 1**:

```
column_id | column_str
1         | spiderman
```

**For phrase 2**:

```
column_id | column_str
2         | potatoes
```

So, it should find the matching substrings in the input in the table column_str column and return its associated id.

I have no error or trial example yet because I do not know where to start.

What I know is that there is the `%LIKE%` matcher. But this is exactly the opposite, something like `%IN_LIKE%`.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server or perhaps Sybase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `INSTR` function:

```
--sample data creation
create table tbl(id int, str varchar(50));
insert into tbl values (1, 'spiderman');
insert into tbl values (2, 'potatoes');

select * from tbl
where instr('I am spiderman and I have a potato', str) > 0;

select * from tbl
where instr('I am a spider and I like potatoes', str) > 0;
```

See [MySQL `INSTR()` function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about some Tricky SQL as below:

```
select dsd
from (select 'potato' as dsd) ss
where (select 'I am spiderman and I have a potato') rlike dsd;
```

Example:

```
mysql> select dsd from (select 'potato' as dsd) ss where (select 'I am spiderman and I have a potato') rlike dsd;
+--------+
| dsd    |
+--------+
| potato |
+--------+
```